# Entity update after deploying Plugin gives 2147220891 Exception ServiceModel.FaultException1 Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Hi i have created and deployed a plug. Using plugin profiler when debug the code i am not getting any error. But when i update the Entity, an error is thrown and here is the log file:

Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Download the details and load with Plug-in Profiler.

-2147220891

Not able to find the solution, i commented everything in my plugin and here are the bare bones of the code and I am still getting the error.

Plugin code snippet:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        if(context.MessageName != "Update")
            return;

        var targetEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

        if(targetEntity.LogicalName != "new_d")
            return;

        ITracingService _TracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        try {

        }
        catch(FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex) {
            _TracingService.Trace(ex.ToString());
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in Update plug-in.", ex);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            _TracingService.Trace("Update: {0}", ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lookup the error code (-2147220891) in the CRM SDK. In the help-file search for Web Service Error Codes. The codes are in hexadecimal format. Yours is 0x80040265, "ISV code aborted the operation.".

Your code snippet does not contain the complete class, but I noticed the Execute method references some variables that do not have a local scope:

- targetEntity
- _DC

Apparently these variables are fields belonging to the plugin class.

Dynamics CRM instantiates plugin classes once and reuses the instances on multiple threads. Using fields on plugin classes is therefore NOT threadsafe.

You will have to remove these fields first.

Your plugin shows multiple other issues:

1. Your code does work that may prove to be unnecessary. E.g. when your plugin is handling the Create or Update message, you do not need to check the existence and type of the Target parameter.
2. Getting values from the entity's Attributes collection should preferrably not be done through the item selector, because attributes having a `NULL` value in the database will not be added to the collection when retrieved from the OrganizationService. Use method `GetAttributeValue<T>` instead.
3. The value in dc_AppId will not contain an Id (`Guid`), but the display name of the record (`string`). Also, should its value not be passed into the FetchXML?
4. In your code you are using the `targetEntity.Id` property. For the Create message this property will return a `Guid.Empty` in the PreValidation and PreOperation stages. In the PostOperation and AsyncOperation stages the Id can be retrieved from the `OutputParameters` collection. (The key is 'id'.)
5. You are using FetchXML to query data. In CRM 2011 it is better to use a `QueryExpression` (or a Linq-query) instead. In plugins you only need FetchXml for aggregate queries (count, sum, average).
6. Note that tracing can only be retrieved from the plugin when an Exception has been thrown.

I restructured your plugin a bit in the snippet below:

```
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        if (context.MessageName != "Create" && context.MessageName != "Update")
            return;

        var targetEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

        if (targetEntity.LogicalName != "new_designconsultation")
            return;

        ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        try
        {
            var dc = service.Retrieve("new_designconsultation", targetEntity.Id,
                new ColumnSet("new_applicationtodesignconsultationid", "unit1apartment"));

            var dc_AppId = dc.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_applicationtodesignconsultationid");

            if (dc_AppId == null)
                return;

            // TODO: pass dc_AppId.Id into your Fetch XML.

            var fetchURAs = @"
<fetch distinct='true' mapping='logical'> 
<entity name='new_ura'> 
    <attribute name='new_uraid'/> 
    <attribute name='new_name'/> 
    <attribute name='new_app_uraid'/>
    <attribute name='suiteapt'/>
        <filter type='and'> 
            <condition attribute='suiteapt' operator='not-null'/>
        </filter>
    </entity> 
</fetch>";

            EntityCollection _URAs = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchURAs));
            // TODO: continue processing here...
        }

        catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
        {
            tracingService.Trace(ex.ToString());
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in Update plug-in.", ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tracingService.Trace("Update: {0}", ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

You can make debugging easier when you attach VS to the W3WP process or to the CRM Asynchronous Service (for asynchronous plugins).

Comment: @ Henk: Appreciate your feedback in shedding light on other issues in code taking time/patience. I have updated the complete class. I have changed to GetAttriburteValue as suggested and also researched about the property. Please comment on other changes i can make to code better. I am still getting the same error. I am debugging my code by getting error log file and using Plugin Profiler. Do  you think that will point to cause of incorrect code?

Comment: Maybe you can share a stacktrace. Also be aware that other plugins than yours can throw exceptions.

Comment: I am not getting any err in VS. The only error is in the form of a log file when i am updating the entity in a browser. I have literally removed all the code except initializing ITracingService, IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory, IOrganizationService service as shown in the code and still receiving the error log file.

Comment: After digging further, there is a conflict with other plugin and deleting the it caused my plugin to work. Thank you for the tips and help. Once again please correct my code if it can be made better.